# How to take date value into variable?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to take value into date variable , I am getting error

> *unable to convert mysql datetime value to system.datetime*

I am using visual studio 2008.
how to sort out this question?
     Dim connStr As String
                Dim SQLstr As String

```
            connStr = String.Format("server=" + LoginForm1.GlobalVariables.serveripaddress + "; user id=" + LoginForm1.GlobalVariables.dbusername + "; password=" + LoginForm1.GlobalVariables.dbpassword + "; database=" + LoginForm1.GlobalVariables.dbnamebroadcast + "; pooling=false; Convert Zero Datetime=True;Allow Zero Datetime=true")
            Dim conn = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            conn.Open()

            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            Dim bct21, bct24, bct27, bct30 As Date

            Dim bct0, bct1, bct2, bct3, bct4, bct5, bct6, bct7, bct8, bct9, bct10, bct11, bct12, bct13, bct14, bct15, bct16, bct17, bct18, bct19, bct20, bct22, bct23, bct25, bct26, bct28, bct29, bct31, bct32, bct33, bct34, bct35 As String
            Dim bct90, bct36, bct37, bct38, bct39, bct40, bct41, bct42, bct43, bct44, bct45, bct46, bct47, bct48, bct50, bct51, bct52, bct53, bct54, bct55, bct56, bct57, bct58, bct59, bct60, bct61, bct62, bct63, bct64, bct65, bct66, bct67, bct68, bct69, bct70, bct71, bct72, bct73, bct74, bct75, bct76, bct77, bct78, bct80, bct81, bct82, bct83, bct84, bct85, bct86, bct87, bct88 As String

Dim clipdetails_ctn As New MySqlCommand("SELECT anatv.id ,anatv.channel_master_id,anatv.program_master_id,anatv.programTelecast,anatv.programDate,anatv.programStartTime,anatv.programEndTime,anatv.programLength,anatv.programSlot,anatv.isGEC,anatv.headline,anatv.reach,anatv.trp,anatv.sharedOrExclusive,anatv.clipType,anatv.typeComment,anatv.clipTag,anatv.tagCommentOther,anatv.tagCommentSpecialFeature,anatv.qcAutoUserId,anatv.qcAutoCurrentTime,anatv.qcAutoCurrentDate,anatv.qcReleaserId,anatv.qcReleaserCurrentTime,anatv.qcReleaserCurrentDate,anatv.user_master_id,anatv.currentTime,anatv.currentDate,anatv.c2n,anatv.c2nTime,anatv.c2nDate,anatv.clip_core_id,anatv.clip_start_time,anatv.clip_end_time,anatv.hourly_clip_name,anatv.cropped_clip_name,anatv.advertise_flag,anatv.breaking_news_flag,anatv.sector_id,anatv.keyword_list,anatv.is_headline,anatv.is_logo,by1.id,by1.clipId,by1.sector_master_id,by1.company_master_id,by1.byline_master_id,by1.otherDetails,by1.currentTime,by1.currentDate,by1.journ_profile_master_id,bykey.id,bykey.clipId,bykey.sector_master_id,bykey.company_master_id,bykey.keyword_master_id_2,bykey.programStatus,bykey.personality_master_id,bykey.beneficialStartTime,bykey.beneficialEndTime,bykey.beneficialTimeDifference,bykey.neutralStartTime,bykey.neutralEndTime,bykey.neutralTimeDifference,bykey.adverseStartTime,bykey.adverseEndTime,bykey.adverseTimeDifference,bykey.totalTimeInSeconds,bykey.keywordSummary,bykey.isKeyMessage,bykey.key_message_master_id,bykey.keyMessageSummary,bykey.source_master_id,bykey.sourceTonality,bykey.sourceSummary,bykey.keywordLevelTag,bykey.keywordLevelTagGEC,bykey.combination_master_id,bykey.clipSummary,bykey.currentDate,vis.id,vis.clipId,vis.sector_master_id,vis.company_master_id,vis.missOrHit,vis.reasonHitMiss,vis.MMB,vis.currentTime,vis.currentDate  from tb_kna_analysis_tv AS anatv,tb_kna_analysis_tv_byline AS by1,tb_kna_analysis_tv_byline_keyword  AS bykey,tb_kna_analysis_tv_visibility  AS vis,tb_kna_b_trans_broadcast_tag AS tag WHERE  anatv.clip_core_id= tag.id and anatv.id= by1.clipId and anatv.id= bykey.clipId and anatv.id=vis.clipId and tag.id = " + LoginForm1.GlobalVariables.qcindex.ToString, conn)
            reader = clipdetails_ctn.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.Read() Then

bct21 = reader.GetString(21) ' here I want take value from select query to bct21
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the ".getstring" because you dont watn to get string

```
bct21 = ctype(reader(21),datetime)
```

or

```
bct21 =reader(21)
```

also you may want to use

```
dim bct as new list (of Datetime)
```

then

```
bct.add(reader(<whatevever>))
```

this will make your variables easier to manage

Comment: I appreciate your help ,but when I am using   bct21 = reader(21) in my code and when i check my databse a values those are getting inseted is  0001-01-01 .automatically it taking value 0001-01-01 if it is null.

Comment: Ishey4 I am inserting a values after selecting from above code.i haven't included my insertion code in above question.

Comment: can you please include the insert code?

are you inserting the values as datetime?